# CSS background-image; Re-sizing

Tags: html, css, resize, background-image

**Situation:** *I have a div element with the logo, nav & intro text inside of it. This needs to have a background-image behind it all.*

**Problem:** *The background-image needs to be the same size (100% width) but also the same height no matter what size the window is. So it can re-size horizontally but i don't want it re-sizing vertically so that it goes smaller vertically.*

**Header - Normal Screen Size** http://s25.postimg.org/fh7npk5am/header_normal.jpg

**Header - Window Resized, Scaled Down** http://s25.postimg.org/685hffwem/header_resized.jpg

Any help or suggestions is appreciated guys! Please just ask if you need any more information or details about this.

----> JSFiddle is in comments<----

Comment: Use jsfiddle or codepen or smth to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: May b this link will help you 

[CSS Links](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: Your code (and jsfiddle) must be in the question proper. Comments don't last forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you might be able to use the "background-size:cover;".
This should keep the background image atleast 100% at all times.

You might want to set the div height to a fixed amount of pixels, such as "height:250px"

Answer (score 0):

Try these css properties:

```
background-size:cover;
```

or

```
background-size:contain;
```

or

```
    html{
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png') no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
    background-color:#0C0C0C;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```